# Why does my script not work on FreeBSD? (awk: syntax error)

Tags: awk, freebsd

Why does [this](https://github.com/jizhang/zabbix-templates/blob/master/php-fpm/php-fpm-check.sh) script not work on FreeBSD? I ran the script on Centos and Debian, all was fine. On FreeBSD (10.2) I encounter the following error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    match($0, "^listen >>>  queue:[[:space:]]+(.*)", <<< 
awk: bailing out at source line 1
-0.9902
```

As an example, here is some output of php-form status:

```
pool:                 www
process manager:      ondemand
start time:           29/Feb/2016:15:18:54 +0200
start since:          2083770
accepted conn:        1467128
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     129
listen queue len:     128
idle processes:       1
active processes:     2
total processes:      3
max active processes: 64
max children reached: 1
slow requests:        0
```

On Centos and Debian, when I run:

```
/path/to/script/php-fpm-check.sh "idle processes" http://127.0.0.1/status
```

I get `1`, but on FreeBSD the error mentioned above.

Note: to avoid having to get above script working, here is a quick script which replicates the problem:

```
echo 'listen queue: 0' | awk '
  match($0, "^listen queue:[[:space:]]+(.*)", a) {
    print a[1]
  }'
```

Comment: Maybe you should show us the script in question :)

Comment: hyperlink in word "this"

Comment: We require a minimum example to reproduce the problem in the question itself.

Comment: i add some example

Comment: Some context is useful but you have a syntax error in an awk script somewhere, so you need to show us that script.

Comment: I already give link to script, https://github.com/jizhang/zabbix-templates/blob/master/php-fpm/php-fpm-check.sh

Comment: We're not interested in following a link to some shell script which happens to contain some awk. Show us the awk script **in the question itself**, then we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3-argument form of `match` is a GNU awk extension ([docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-match_0028_0029-function)). You'll have to find another way to capture the match (perhaps using the RSTART and RLENGTH variables set as a side-effect of match()), or install gawk on your freebsd system.

Answer (score 0):

The awk script in your case is basically checking for lines that match `abc def: xyz` (with a nonzero amount of whitespace after the colon) and printing `xyz` when they do.

Assuming the `abc def` string itself never contains a colon, then you could use `:[[:space:]]+` as your field separator, then when `^abc def:`  matches, you can just print the second field.

```
# example data
NGINX_STATS="
listen queue:         0
idle processes:       1"

ZBX_REQ_DATA="idle processes"

RESULT=$(echo "$NGINX_STATS" |
         awk  -F ':[[:space:]]+'  '/'"$ZBX_REQ_DATA"':[[:space:]]+/ { print $2 }')

echo $RESULT
```